# Why does Google sample code fall back to GIDSignIn handling if FUIAuth handling fails?

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, google-identity

I was browsing through the iOS source for Google's sample app Friendly Pix and noticed something I don't understand about the sign-in logic they use. Specifically, in their `AppDelegate.swift` code (full source [here](https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix-ios/blob/master/FriendlyPix/AppDelegate.swift)), they use the following to set up the authorization properties:

```
let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
authUI?.delegate = self
authUI?.tosurl = kFirebaseTermsOfService
authUI?.isSignInWithEmailHidden = true
let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [FUIGoogleAuth(), FUIFacebookAuth()]
authUI?.providers = providers
```

Later, they handle the sign-in callback by eventually calling this method:

```
func handleOpenUrl(_ url: URL, sourceApplication: String?) -> Bool {
    if FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.handleOpen(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication) ?? false {
        return true
    }
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: nil)
}
```

This brings me to my question: why do they call `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(...)`? Since `FUIGoogleAuth()` is one of the providers for `FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()`, wouldn't the call to `FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.handleOpen(...)` handle any Google sign-in internally? Under what circumstances would the `handle()` of `GIDSignIn` method do anything that wasn't already done by calling the `handleOpen()` method of `FUIAuth`?

I though perhaps this was to deal with the possibility that `FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()` can return `nil`, However, if that were to happen, I don't think the app would ever progress this far, because the authentication that triggers the call-back is:

```
let authViewController = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.authViewController()
authViewController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
self.present(authViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

which would crash on the last line if `authViewController` were `nil` (which would happen if `FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()` returned `nil`).

Answer (score 0):

I was using the now-deprecated Firebase Invites and it wasn't accepting Firebase Auth tokens. I'm updating the code, should be out soon.